# Gatsby app with Shopify integration not rendering images

Tags: reactjs, shopify, gatsby

I am working on a Shopify integration for a Gatsby app which for the most part is doing what it's supposed to do but it's not rendering the images as it's supposed to. Here is my React code.

```
const ProductTemplate = ({ pageContext }) => {
const { product } = pageContext
return (
  <Layout>
    <h1>{product.title}</h1>
    <div>{product.description}</div>

    <MyMeta
      title="Product Page"
      description="Individual Product"
      image={product.images.originalSrc}
      groups={[
       {
         name: 'shopify',
         order: 1,
       },
      ]}
    />
```

and my gatsby-node.js has the following

```
const path = require(`path`)
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
const { createPage } = actions
// Query for all products in Shopify
const result = await graphql(`
  query {
    allShopifyProduct(sort: { fields: [title] }) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          shopifyId
          handle
          description
          availableForSale
          images {
            id
            originalSrc
          }
          priceRange {
            maxVariantPrice {
            amount
          }
          minVariantPrice {
            amount
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
`)
```

The title and description display fine but the image doesn't render.

The originalSrc does seem to bring back values as expected

In my graphql explorer, if I query using this

```
query MyQuery {
  allShopifyProduct {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        images {
          originalSrc
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following

```
{
"data": {
  "allShopifyProduct": {
  "edges": [
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "Shopify__Product__Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzY1NDQ0NTk3MjcwMzg=",
        "images": [
          {
            "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0539/2980/3966/products/longsleeve.jpg?v=1614656756"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "Shopify__Product__Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzY1NDQzNzczODEwNTQ=",
        "images": [
          {
            "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0539/2980/3966/products/pajamas.jpg?v=1614654661"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "Shopify__Product__Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzY1NDQ0NTQwMjU0MDY=",
        "images": [
          {
            "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0539/2980/3966/products/shortsleeves.jpg?v=1614656651"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "node": {
        "id": "Shopify__Product__Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzY1NDQ0NDkxNDI5NzQ=",
        "images": [
          {
            "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0539/2980/3966/products/khakhi.jpg?v=1614656544"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
 }
 },
 "extensions": {}
}
```

Comment: And what's the issue? Broken image? Are you using `gatsby-image` in `<MyMeta>` component?

Comment: So the issue is just that the image doesn't show up. Should I be using gatsby-image as opposed to the html img tag?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but I can't see that code, that's why I was asking. Is the `originalSrc` being retrieved properly?

Comment: Yes it does. I added the graphql response in the post.

Comment: Thanks! The only remaining thing I need to know is the `<MyMeta>` component to check how are you printing the image

Comment: So that's one's another npm module but the image is working with another project. So really it maybe something to do with the originalSrc I would think.

Comment: I would point to <MyMeta> component

Comment: can you show the real code in your frontend where you use that image in a HTML tag?

Comment: The real code is the first block which has the MyMeta tag.

Comment: I guess if I just have to add an image, should I reference it as product.images.originalSrc or product.images[originalSrc] ?

Answer (score 0):

`images` returns an array, provide the index of the image you want to retrieve / iterate over them

```
<MyMeta
      title="Product Page"
      description="Individual Product"
      image={product.images[0].originalSrc}
      groups={[
       {
         name: 'shopify',
         order: 1,
       },
      ]}
    />
```